# What is the purpose of having Visibility option under 'Row Visibility' and also under Row properties windows (F4)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2016

We can right click on a row and click on Row Visibility to -> Show/Hide/Expr

Also, when we select the row and press F4 (properties window), there is an option for Visibility that allows us to set 'Hidden' to True/False/Expr

What is the purpose of having this at 2 places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the same functionality provided in 2 different places.
They have same meaning, just 2 ways to navigate and use whichever you like

Comment: This is correct.  Any option you set in the graphical menus is simply applying those values to the relevant property in the Properties Window.